# jquery no conflict with other javascript libraries

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery widget which can be added in any websites. I am using jQuery1.7.
I am in doubt that it will conflict with other javascript libraries jQuery older versions, mootools, prototype etc). I found the method `jquery.noconflict()`. Can anybody please give me the exact syntax to use and also where to add this in my script?

Thanks in advance for the response.

Thank you Shlomi Komemi for suggesting the link.

I am updating the answer this link

[Can I use multiple versions of jQuery on the same page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566595/can-i-use-multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page)

Comment: like this ? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566595/can-i-use-multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page

Answer (score 3):

```
<script src="jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script>jQuery.noConflict();</script>
```

But once this has been done you have to make sure you always call Jquery with the whole word instead of the $ sign.

Comment: Thank you Sathya for the quick response. You are saying that we dont need to add anything else in this code right?. Can this avoid conflict with other libraries also?

Comment: for calling jquery use  whole word jQuery instead of the $ sign, and this will avoid conflict with other libs as well